# How to use ticketmaster API in swift

Tags: json, swift, decodable, ticketmaster

This is the first time I have tried to use an API, I get the error "keyNotFound" Could someone point me in the right direction for understanding this better? Here is a link to their documentation: https://developer.ticketmaster.com/products-and-docs/apis/discovery-api/v2/#anchor_find

```
let apiKey = "************"
    
    struct EventResponse : Decodable{
        let events : [Event]
    }
    
    struct Event : Decodable{
        let id : String?
    }
    
    func fetchTMEvents() async throws -> [Event]{
        let urlTM = URL(string: "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=\(apiKey)")!
        let(data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: urlTM)
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(EventResponse.self, from: data)
        return decoded.events
    }
```

```
Task {
            do {
                let events = try await fetchTMEvents()
                print("API results \(events)")
            } catch {
                print("API error \(error)")
            }
        }
```

Full error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil) ("events").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: show the full error message, it usually tells you exactly what is wrong. Show the code for your `EventResponse` and `Event`. Do they match **exactly** what the docs says? Try adding `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` after the `let(data, _) = try await ...`

Comment: full error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"events\", intValue: nil) (\"events\").", underlyingError: nil)) @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: The error is telling you that the data you get from the server does not match your
 `EventResponse` model (or sub models).
Show the code for your `EventResponse` and `Event`, together with the `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`.
It seems you have `let events: [Event]` in your models somewhere, but it needs `let events: [Event]?`
Or you are not getting the response you think you should be getting, the `print` will tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these test models to fetch then decode the `events`.
The example code in SwiftUI shows how to display the results.

Note, you must have a valid `apiKey` otherwise the response will not be decodable.

To get the full set of struct models, just copy the json data (all of it) to
https://app.quicktype.io/ and the bulk of the code is generated for you. **Adjust that
code** to suit your needs.

You will have to consult the docs to determine which struct/properties are optional,
then add `?` to them.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var events: [Event] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(events) { event in
            Text(event.name)
        }
        .task {
            do {
                if let results = try await fetchTMEvents() {
                    events = results
                }
            } catch {
                print("---> error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchTMEvents() async throws -> [Event]? {
        let apiKey = "xxxxxxx"
        let urlTM = URL(string: "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=\(apiKey)")!
        let(data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: urlTM)
        // print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(EventResponse.self, from: data)
        return decoded.embedded.events
    }
}

struct EventResponse: Codable {
    let embedded: ResponseEmbedded
    let page: Page

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case page
        case embedded = "_embedded"
    }
}

struct ResponseEmbedded: Codable {
    let events: [Event]?
}

struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    let name, type, id, url, locale: String
}

struct Page: Codable {
    let size, totalElements, totalPages, number: Int
}
```